# Need to use socket programming to write an echo server that utilizes the TCP/IP protocol, but my connection to the server is failing

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

Both programs compile, and I'm able to successfully create a socket, but the connection to the server fails. This is basically a TCP echo program.
PS. I'm new here so IDK how to use this, I don't have much programming experience so bare with me.

[tcp echo client-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RnVt.png)

[tcp echo client-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtPs.png)

[tcp echo server-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juyjs.png)

[tcp echo server-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idTDn.png)

Compiling/Running server gives me: Server not fully implemented...
Compiling/Running client gives me: Socket successfully created..Error: connection to the server failed!

```
**// TCP echo client program**
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[ ])      // Three arguments to be checked later
{
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;        // Server socket address data structure
    char *servIP = argv[1];             // Server IP address from command line
    int servPort = atoi(argv[2]);       // Server port number from command line
    char *message = argv[3];            // Message specified on the command line
    char buffer [512 + 1];
    char* ptr = buffer;
    int len; 
    int max_len = sizeof(buffer); 
    int sock_descrip; 

    // Check for correct number of command line arguments
    if(argc != 4) {                                               
        printf("tcp-echo-client [IP address] [Port] [Message]\n");                             
        exit (1);
    }                                                

    // Populate socket address for the server
    memset (&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));        // Initialize data structure
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                  // This is an IPv4 address
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   // Server IP address
    servAddr.sin_port = servPort;                   // Server port number
    
    // Create a TCP socket stream
    int sock;
    if ((sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
        printf("Error: socket creation failed!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 

    // Connect  to the server
    if ((connect (sock, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))) == -1) {
        printf("Error: connection to the server failed!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
     else
        printf("Connected to the server..\n"); 

    // Send data to the server...
    send(sock_descrip, message, strlen(message),0);
    int x;
    while ((x = recv(sock_descrip, ptr, max_len,0))>0)
    {
        ptr += x;
        max_len -= x;
        len += x;
    }
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    printf("Echoed string received: %s %c", buffer,*message);

    // Receive data back from the server..
        
    //  Loop while receiving data... 
    //      print data...
    //  end-while loop  

    // Close socket
    close (sock);
    
    // Stop program
    exit (0);
    
} // End main


**//TCP Echo server program**
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFLEN  512                                         // Maximum length of buffer
#define PORT    9988                                        // Fixed server port number

int main (void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;                      // Data structure for server address
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;                      // Data structure for client address
    int client_address_len = 0;
    char buffer [512];
    char* ptr = buffer;
    int len;
    int max_len = BUFLEN; 
    int sock_descrip; 
        
    
    // Populate socket address for the server
    memset (&server_address, 0, sizeof (server_address));   // Initialize server address data structure
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;                    // Populate family field - IPV4 protocol
    server_address.sin_port = PORT;                         // Set port number
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;            // Set IP address to IPv4 value for loacalhost
        
    // Create a TCP socket; returns -1 on failure
    int listen_sock;
    if ((listen_sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
        printf("Error: Listen socket failed!\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    // Bind the socket to the server address; returns -1 on failure
    if ((bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof (server_address))) == -1) {
        printf("Error: binding failed!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    
    printf("Server not fully implemented...\n");
    
    // Listen for connections...
    int wait_size; 
    if (listen(listen_sock, wait_size) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: listening failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(;;)
    {
        if(sock_descrip=accept(listen_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_len) == -1)
        {
            printf("Error: accepting failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        int x; 
        while ((x = recv(sock_descrip, ptr, max_len, 0)) > 0)
        {
            ptr += x;
            max_len -= x; 
            len += x; 
        }
        send(sock_descrip,buffer,len,0);  
    }
    
    // Echo data back to the client...
        
    close (listen_sock);                                    // Close descriptor referencing server socket
    
} // End main
```

Comment: your code looks ok at first glance. What is the setup for the connection? are the client and server running on different machines? are they connected through wifi or wired ethernet?

Comment: there are **lots** of uninitialized variables. I suggest to turn on all warning of your compiler and run the programs through valgrind

Comment: It's not OK.  You MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like send/recv.  That avoids, for instance, writing a null to an array offset [-1].

Comment: @snus74 - I'm using virtual box (ubuntu), running on different terminals, connected through wifi.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around the assignment:

```
if(
(sock_descrip=accept(listen_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_len))
 == -1)
```

Comment: Added the parentheses and getting the same output as above.

Comment: Which parameters you using when executing client program?

Comment: ./tcp_echo_client 127.0.0.1 8899 message

Comment: port defined as #define PORT    9988  for server. not 8899

Comment: okay i fixed that to: ./tcp_echo_client 127.0.0.1 9988 message - now, it says socket successfully created..connected to the server..echoed string received but in server, it says server not fully implemented

Comment: @thewalkingdev So fully implement it, or take out the `printf()` that says it isn't. Hard to see what you're expecting here.